# Is there an AWS option which can securely store users for my web and mobile app?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services

Is there a service which would allow me to securely manage user accounts?

I see that I can use IAM to manage federated users with providers such as Facebook and Google. (see link below) But I am not seeing any guidance on managing user credentials for the web and mobile apps. Normally these details are stored in the database with everything else but I'd prefer to instead using an Amazon service if that is an option. Given all of the compromises in the last few years I'd like to take every measure that I can.

Manage Federation: http://aws.amazon.com/iam/details/manage-federation/

Once I have a user account I can use Token Vending Machine or the newer option Security Token Service to allow that user to access other services as that user such as S3. It does not look like I would use IAM to store user accounts for the website or mobile apps.

Should I just store user credentials in my own database and set it up with an OAuth 2 Provider so I can use them as federated user with AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's isn't any service that will allow you to manage users in your app.

If you don't want to store credentials in the database you can go with either OAuth 2 or OpenID.  It's supported by all the main websites: Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc. You'll find that most web frameworks have third party libraries that support OAuth and OpenID.  Wether you want to store your credentials in your local database or use OAuth/OpenID depends on how much you trust your server to be secure and how well are you backing up your database. Oauth/OpenID are generally pretty secure, they are widely used by thousands if not millions of apps.

The Manage Federation link only applies to users in AIM and how they can access the AWS Console or the AWS Apis only.

Comment: Thanks @Rico. I think what I will be doing is storing these details in the Postgres database and lock down access to it, perhaps requiring a stored procedure and denying select access so all rows cannot be returned. That could help cut down on potential exploits. I will also limit access to the database.

Comment: I recently found this video from a Postgres conference which explains how user data can be protected with a superuser and stored procedure. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuLMIQBB4Ew